# Why is the 'Wallet' app using up all of my battery?

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, wallet

My battery seemed to be draining rather fast.

I opened the battery settings, and it turns out that the wallet is responsible for 60% of my battery usage. This is an unexpected amount. I only used the app once today, and it is not open in the active apps tray either.

What could be causing this?

Comment: iPad/iPhone? Which one? What version of iOS?

Comment: Check the tags.

Comment: @SteveChambers iPad doesn't have a Wallet app